# помогите правильно распарсить json средствами javascript (google apps script)

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

есть json содержащий что-то вроде

```
[
  {
    "contents": [
      {
        "amount": 40,
        "type_id": 2389
      },
      {
        "amount": 40,
        "type_id": 2390
      }
    ],
    "last_cycle_start": "2024-03-06T23:34:32Z",
    "latitude": 1.7929432392120361,
    "longitude": 5.795536994934082,
    "pin_id": 1044610962318,
    "schematic_id": 67,
    "type_id": 2480
  },
  {
    "contents": [
      {
        "amount": 40,
        "type_id": 2389
      },
      {
        "amount": 40,
        "type_id": 2390
      }
    ],
    "last_cycle_start": "2024-03-06T23:34:32Z",
    "latitude": 1.7809253931045532,
    "longitude": 5.796088695526123,
    "pin_id": 1044610962322,
    "schematic_id": 67,
    "type_id": 2480
  }
]
```

> здесь два элемента, для примера достаточно

Собственно не получается получить все свойства используя метод JSON.parse,
т.е. собственно, получается обойти элементы по индексу или иными способами.
Получаю индексы и могу их вывести, а получить сами свойства не получается ни по индексу ни по ключу.

с более простым json-объектом, состоящим из одного элемента, все хорошо.

Прошу подсказать как правильно парсить такие и/или более сложные объекты json

функция:

```
function GetDataInJsonMixSimple_consumption(data_json,id_resource){
  var DATA = JSON.parse(data_json, function(key, value){ return (value);}
  );
  quantity = 0;
  for (let i=0;i<DATA.length; i++){
      var objt = DATA[i];

      type_id = objt.type_id;
      //console.log("type_id",type_id);
      if (type_id == 2480){
        contents = objt.contents;
        //console.log("contents",contents);
        
        for (let j=0;j<contents.length; j++){
          //console.log("content",contents[j]);
          if (contents[j].type_id == id_resource) {
            quantity += contents[j].amount;
          }
        }
      }
      
  }
  console.log("quantity",quantity);
  return quantity;
}

let consumption_quantity = GetDataInJsonMixSimple_consumption(data_json1, 2389);
```

Comment: 1. пример как ты пробовал парсить.
2. какие свойства получаеш какие нет.
3. есть много приложений каторые приводят вот такую груду JSON-а в читаемый вид. например: https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print

Comment: нужно сравнивать "type_id" с эталоном и при совпадении складывать значение определенный ключей "amount"
но я даже вытянуть содержимое "type_id" с первого значения не могу
я его и по индексу и через ключ и через точку получить пробовал...  
максимум в ответ получаю индекс

Comment: или ничего не получаю 
ReferenceError: content is not defined

Comment: скинь код, как ты пробовал. ReferenceError, ну и правильно, тут нету content  есть content(s)

Comment: правильно говорят правильно заданный вопрос = половина ответа 
https://pasteb.in/?14f4d5255dc5eb03#HiKWyFQF8zsR5TMPWpV4yjjuuxX3CnYfMYeDRpdXBq6Q
запустилось! спасибо за наводку на ответ,
но все равно с ошибкой...
Ошибка
SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
GetDataInJsonMixSimple_consumption
@ Код.gs:9

>> 9 строка это var DATA = JSON.parse(data_json, function(key, value){ return (value);} 
на что он ругается непонятно

Comment: исходный код можно добавить прямо в вопросе(это для дальнейшых вопросов)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const json = [
  {
    contents: [
      {
        amount: 25,
        type_id: 2389,
      },
      {
        amount: 40,
        type_id: 2390,
      },
    ],
    type_id: 2480,
  },
  {
    contents: [
      {
        amount: 25,
        type_id: 2389,
      },
      {
        amount: 40,
        type_id: 2390,
      },
    ],
    type_id: 2480,
  },
  {
    type_id: 2481,
    contents: [
      {
        amount: 25,
        type_id: 2389,
      },
      {
        amount: 40,
        type_id: 2390,
      },
    ],
  },
];

//то что у тебя есть и так работает(просто чуток подчистил)
const getQuantity = (json, approvedInnerId) => {
  const parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);
  let quantity = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < parsedJson.length; i++) {
    const { type_id, contents } = parsedJson[i];

    if (type_id == 2480) {
      for (let j = 0; j < contents.length; j++) {
        const { type_id, amount } = contents[j];
        if (type_id == approvedInnerId) {
          quantity += amount;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return quantity;
};

//более быстрый вариант реализации
const getQuantityFaster = (json, approvedInnerId) => {
  const APPROVED_ROOT_ID = 2480;
  let quantity = 0;
  let temporaryAmountForUpQuantity = 0;
  let amount = 0;
  JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => {
    if (key === "amount") {
      amount = value;
    }
    const isCorrectInnerId = key === "type_id" && value === approvedInnerId;
    if (isCorrectInnerId) {
      temporaryAmountForUpQuantity = amount;
    }
    const isCorrectRootId = value?.contents && value?.type_id === APPROVED_ROOT_ID;
    if (isCorrectRootId) {
      quantity += temporaryAmountForUpQuantity;
    }
    return value;
  });

  return quantity;
};


const quantity = getQuantity(JSON.stringify(json), 2389);
const quantity2 = getQuantityFaster(JSON.stringify(json), 2390);

console.log(quantity)
console.log(quantity2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот более читаемый вариант кода:

```
const stringify = (json) => {
  return JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
}

const getQuantity = (json, approvedInnerId) => {
  const parsedJson = JSON.parse(stringify(json));
  let quantity = 0;
  parsedJson.forEach(item => {
    if (item.type_id == 2480) {
      item.contents.forEach(content => {
        if (content.type_id == approvedInnerId) {
          quantity += content.amount;
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return quantity;
};

const x = () => {
  console.log(getQuantity(json, 2390));
  console.log(getQuantity(json, 2389));
}
```